# How to combine microservice and monolith data for operational reporting?

Tags: database, microservices, reporting, monolithic

I am looking for strategic advice about our operational reporting strategy. Currently, we have an effective monolith that has been in existence for decades. Over the past couple years, we have tried to adopt a microservice architecture but now we are in a weird spot where we have 1 monolith (with a large relational database) and several microservices (with small relational databases) and we need to conduct operational reporting on the microservices. The microservices need to be combined with data from the monolith to be valuable so we are looking at options to achieve this.

So far, we are considering the following:

1. data replication to the monolith to leverage its reporting functionality (either dual write OR event sourcing)
2. sync both to a data warehouse and use a BI tool for both. This path may not be ideal for operational reporting since it’s OLAP not OLTP.

What are design patterns should we consider? What are some pros and cons for the options we are considering?

Comment: CQRS comes to mind, with µs events that update a query database model. This model can live in the monolith database, or a separate one.